# Clone BigQuery Project to another account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

Due to a change in the business I need to copy a whole BigQuery project from one account to another, also, the accounts are not related and is not possible to link it in any way.

Throughout the CLI I was able to export a table to Cloud Storage in a dataset. Also, list tables in a dataset looks possible so loop over it shouldn't be a problem.

But I can't find any suitable way to manage the datasets neither for exporting or creating in the new account so it left a lot of manual task.

I'm missing something? There is a way to export the whole project with all datasets or a manual task will be always required?

The data structure is not complex at all:

```
     Project -> dataset -> table
                        -> table
                        -> ...

             -> dataset -> table
                        -> table
                        -> ...
             -> ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't copy the whole project at once but you can try to automate the copy using a script in `Python` like this:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import os

source_project = "<your source project>"
new_project = "<your new project>"

#I suppose that you have access to the source project in your new project
client = bigquery.Client(project=source_project)

datasets = []

#List all the datasets in the source project and save it in a list
for i in client.list_datasets():    
     datasets.append(i.dataset_id)

#For all the datasets, build the commands and then execute them
for i in datasets:
    create_command = "bq mk -d " + i
    copy_command = "bq mk --transfer_config --project_id=" + new_project + " --data_source=cross_region_copy --target_dataset=" +  i + " --display_name='My Dataset Copy' --params='{\"source_dataset_id\":\"" + i + "\",\"source_project_id\":\"" + source_project + "\",\"overwrite_destination_table\":\"true\"}'"
    os.system(create_command)
    os.system(copy_command)
```

Comment: I just realized, the `bq mk --transferconfig` command, create a recurrent copy every 24 hours inside data transfer.

Comment: Yes. If you need, you can use the --schedule parameter and specify a different schedule (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cronref#schedule_format).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Bigquery Data Transfer service](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/transfer-service-overview) for this. You can't copy all your project, but dataset per dataset. You can script this if you have a lot of dataset.

Be careful, you don't export from the source project to a target project, you import into the target project from the source project (I mean you have to define the transfert in the destination project)

Answer (score 1):

To copy the dataset from one project to another project then you can use the below command to make the transfer job:

```
bq mk --transfer_config --project_id=[PROJECT_ID] --data_source=[DATA_SOURCE] --target_dataset=[DATASET] --display_name=[NAME] --params='[PARAMETERS]'
```

where PROJECT_ID : The destination project_ID
DATA_SOURCE : cross_region_copy
DATASET : Target dataset
NAME : Display name of your job.
PARAMETERS : Source project ID, Source Dataset ID and other parameteres can be defined( overwrite destination table etc.)

You can go through this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/copying-datasets#cli) for detailed explanation.